# How to select the button element with a certain value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time selecting all the buttons with value "bar" using jquery.

```
<div id="1">

   <button>foo</button>
   <button>bar</button>

   <button>foo</button>
   <button>bar</button>

</div>
```

please note I must start the select from div with id="1"

so something like ... `$(#"1 button ....")`

Thanks!

Comment: i am not sure that 1 is proper id name

Comment: @nevermind It's a valid HTML5 id.

Comment: @BlackSheep, Yeees! Finally... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#1').children('button').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === 'bar';
});
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this and i'm hiding the bars, but won't work. see: http://jsfiddle.net/jtQcF/

Comment: You need to load jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/jtQcF/1/... check your console for errors, it's your friend!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:contains()` selector

```
$("#1 button:contains('bar')");
```